# parallel programming

Tags: c#

i wonder if its possible to use parallel programing in web applications. is it possible to have such things

Parallel.For(2, 20, (i) =>
{
    var result = SumRootN(i);
    Console.WriteLine("root {0} : {1} ", i, result);
});

in web?

Comment: Are you expecting specific problems?

Comment: -1 Misleading title for a trivial question

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You should take a lap around the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and web [page about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), to avoid getting downvotes for incomplete or otherwise non-optimal questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use parallel extensions in websites.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use parallel extensions. Also, the more you use, the faster your application will be. Nowadays I would say you MUST use it if you want truly take advance of the newest hardwares.